# Adding SSL support to Python 2.6

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I tried using the `ssl` module in Python 2.6 but I was told that it wasn't available. After installing OpenSSL, I recompiled 2.6 but the problem persists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the OpenSSL development libraries?  I had to install `openssl-devel` on CentOS, for example.  On Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get build-dep python2.5` did the trick (even for Python 2.6).

Answer (score -1):

Use the binaries provided by python.org or by your OS distributor.  It's a lot easier than building it yourself, and all the features are usually compiled in.

If you really need to build it yourself, you'll need to provide more information here about what build options you provided, what your environment is like, and perhaps provide some logs.

Comment: I installed it via a tar file under Ubuntu Linux 8.10. Just decompressed it, ran ./configure;make;sudo make install and was done. Its just that I can't get ssl to import.

Answer (score -4):

Use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) with the openssl binary.

Comment: except that subprocess is fine and part of the std library (note: i didn't downvote you)

Comment: pexpect has the added benefit of allowing one to wait for certain actions by openssl to finish before sending more data to STDOUT. This nicety would have to be coded manually otherwise.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question. If you have software that looks for ssl or _ssl, installing pexpect doesn't help you.