# HTTPS request results in reset connection in Windows with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, https, python-3.x, cygwin

When I use the following function with the Python 3.2.3 package in cygwin it hangs on any request to any https host. It will throw with this error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer, after 60 seconds.

UPDATE: I thought it was limited to only cygwin, but this also happens in Windows 7 64bit with Python 3.3. I'll try 3.2 right now. The error when using the windows command shell is: 
urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

UPDATE2(Electric-Bugaloo): This is limited to a couple of sites that I'm trying to use. I tested against google and other major sites with no issue. It appears it's related to this bug:

http://bugs.python.org/issue16361

Specifically, the server is hanging after the client-hello. It's due to the version of openssl that shipped with the compiled versions of python3.2 and 3.3. It's mis-identifying the ssl version of the server. Now I need code to auto downgrade my version of ssl to sslv3 when opening a connection to the affected sites like in this post:

[How to use urllib2 to get a webpage using SSLv3 encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039859/how-to-use-urllib2-to-get-a-webpage-using-sslv3-encryption)

but I can't get it to work.

```
def worker(url, body=None, bt=None):
    '''This function does all the requests to wherever for data

    takes in a url, optional body utf-8 encoded please, and optional body type'''

    hdrs = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                   'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                   'User-Agent': "My kewl Python tewl!"}
    if 'myweirdurl' in url:
        hdrs = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                   'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                   'User-Agent': "Netscape 6.0"}

    if bt:
        hdrs['Content-Type'] = bt
    urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen
    Request = urllib.request.Request
    start_req = time.time()
    logger.debug('request start: {}'.format(datetime.now().ctime()))
    if 'password' not in url:
        logger.debug('request url: {}'.format(url))
    req = Request(url, data=body, headers=hdrs)
    try:
        if body:
            logger.debug("body: {}".format(body))
            handle = urlopen(req, data=body, timeout=298)
        else:
            handle = urlopen(req, timeout=298)
    except socket.error as se:
        logger.error(se)
        logger.error(se.errno)
        logger.error(type(se))
        if hasattr(se, 'errno') == 60: 
            logger.error("returning: Request Timed Out")
            return 'Request Timed Out'
    except URLError as ue:
        end_time = time.time()
        logger.error(ue)
        logger.error(hasattr(ue, 'code'))
        logger.error(hasattr(ue, 'errno'))
        logger.error(hasattr(ue, 'reason'))
        if hasattr(ue, 'code'):
            logger.warn('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
            logger.error('Error code: {}'.format(ue.code))
            if ue.code == 404:
                return "Resource Not Found (404)"
        elif hasattr(ue, 'reason') :
            logger.warn('We failed to reach a server with {}'.format(url))
            logger.error('Reason: {}'.format(ue.reason))

            logger.error(type(ue.reason))
            logger.error(ue.reason.errno)
            if ue.reason == 'Operation timed out':
                logger.error("Arrggghh, timed out!")
            else:
                logger.error("Why U no match my reason?")
                if ue.reason.errno == 60:
                    return "Operation timed out"
        elif hasattr(ue, 'errno'):
            logger.warn(ue.reason)
            logger.error('Error code: {}'.format(ue.errno))
            if ue.errno == 60:
                return "Operation timed out"
        logger.error("req time: {}".format(end_time - start_req))
        logger.error("returning: Server Error")
        return "Server Error"
    else:
        resp_headers = dict(handle.info())
        logger.debug('Here are the headers of the page : {}'.format(resp_headers))
        logger.debug("The true URL in case of redirects {}".format(handle.geturl()))           
        try:
            ce = resp_headers['Content-Encoding']
        except KeyError as ke:
            ce = None
        else:
            logger.debug('Content-Encoding: {}'.format(ce))
        try:
            ct = resp_headers['Content-Type']
        except KeyError as ke:
            ct = None            
        else:
            logger.debug('Content-Type: {}'.format(ct))
        if ce == "gzip":
            logger.debug("Unzipping payload")
            bi = BytesIO(handle.read())
            gf = GzipFile(fileobj=bi, mode="rb")
            if "charset=utf-8" in ct.lower() or ct == 'text/html' or ct == 'text/plain':
                payload = gf.read().decode("utf-8")
            else:
                logger.debug("Unknown content type: {}".format(ct))
                sys.exit()
            return payload
        else:
            if ct is not None and "charset=utf-8" in ct.lower() or ct == 'text/html' or ct == 'text/plain':
                return handle.read().decode("utf-8")
            else:
                logger.debug("Unknown content type: {}".format(ct))
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: have you tried it with urllib2 too?

Comment: Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.   
    
        >>> import urllib2
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
            import urllib2
        ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Comment: sorry my bad, i was thinking in python2 :) on the other hand, try putting as the user-agent string a real browser user-agent string (http://www.useragentstring.com/). also try to open some other https urls and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: Good idea, I tried that and it still has the same problem. This same code works flawlessly on my FreeBSD machine running Python 3.2. :(

Comment: do you have openssl installed on the machine where the problem occurred?

Comment: Yeah, I installed all ssl related binaries and source for cygwin using the package system. And I added a windows dll, but still no dice.

Comment: are you using a firewall maybe?

Comment: No firewall is in use on either the windows 7 64bit or the windows xp 32bit test hosts I have used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, here's the code block necessary to make this work on Windows:

```
'''had to add this windows specific block to handle this bug in urllib2:
http://bugs.python.org/issue11220
'''
if "windows" in platform().lower():
    if 'my_wacky_url' or 'my_other_wacky_url' in url.lower():
        import ssl
        ssl_context = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(
                                              context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(ssl_context)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
#end of urllib workaround
```

I added this blob right before the first try: block and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the assistance andrean!