# Python 10054 error when trying to log in to airline website using Requests Library

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, python-requests

I'm learning python and as my first project I want to login to several airline websites and scrape my frequent flyer Mile info.  I have successfully been able to login and scrape American Airlines and United but I am unable to do it on Delta, USairways, and Britishairways.

The methodology that I have been using is watching network traffic from Fiddler2, Chrome, or Firebug.  Wireshark seems too complicated at the moment.

For my script to work with American and United scraping all I did was watch the traffic on fiddler2, copy the FORM DATA and REQUEST HEADER DATA and then use the python 3rd party Requests library to access the data.  Very simple. Very Easy.  The other airline website are giving me a lot of trouble.

Let's talk about British Airways specifically.  Below are pictures of the FORM DATA and REQUEST HEADER DATA that I took from fiddler when I logged into my dummy BA account.  I have also included the test script that I have been using.  I wrote two different versions. One using the Requests library and one using urllib.  They both produce the same error but I thought I would provide both to make it easier for somebody to help me if they didn't have the Requests library imported.  Use the one you would like.

Basically, when I make a request.post I am getting a

10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'  error.

I have no idea what is going on.  Been searching for 3 days and come up with nothing.  I hope somebody can help me.  The below code is using my dummy BA account info.  username:python_noob     password:p4ssword.  Feel free to use and test it.

Here are some pictures to the fiddler2 data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8y40.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfvhl.jpg

```
import requests

import urllib


def get_BA_login_using_requests ():
    url_loginSubmit1 = 'https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us'

    url_viewaccount1 = 'https://www.britishairways.com/travel/viewaccount/public/en_us?eId=106011'
    url_viewaccount2 = 'https://www.britishairways.com/travel/viewaccount/execclub/_gf/en_us?eId=106011'


    form_data = {
        'Directional_Login':'',
        'eId':'109001',
        'password':'p4ssword',
        'membershipNumber':'python_noob',
        }


    request_headers= {
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11',

        'Cookie': 'BIGipServerba.com-port80=997762723.20480.0000; v1st=EDAB42A278BE913B; BASessionA=kDtBQWGclJymXtlsTXyYtykDLLsy3KQKvd3wMrbygd7JZZPJfJz2!-1893405604!clx42al01-wl01.baplc.com!7001!-1!-407095676!clx43al01-wl01.baplc.com!7001!-1; BIGipServerba.com-port81=997762723.20736.0000; BA_COUNTRY_CHOICE_COOKIE=us; Allow_BA_Cookies=accepted; BA_COUNTRY_CHOICE_COOKIE=US; opvsreferrer=functional/home/home_us.jsp; realreferrer=; __utma=28787695.2144676753.1356203603.1356203603.1356203603.1; __utmb=28787695.1.10.1356203603; __utmc=28787695; __utmz=28787695.1356203603.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); fsr.s={"v":-2,"rid":"d464cf7-82608645-1f31-3926-49807","ru":"http://www.britishairways.com/travel/globalgateway.jsp/global/public/en_","r":"www.britishairways.com","st":"","to":3,"c":"http://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_us","pv":1,"lc":{"d0":{"v":1,"s":false}},"cd":0}',

        'Content-Length':'78',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

        'Origin':'https://www.britishairways.com',
        'Referer':'https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us',

        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Host':'www.britishairways.com',
        }



    print ('Trying to login to British Airways using Requests Library (takes about 1 minute for error to occur)')


    try:
        r1 = requests.post(url_loginSubmit1, data = form_data, headers = request_headers)
    print ('it worked')
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "An exception of type {0} occured, these were the arguments:\n{1!r}"
        print (msg.format(type(e).__name__, e.args))


    return







def get_BA_login_using_urllib():
    """Tries to request the URL. Returns True if the request was successful; false otherwise.
    https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us

    response -- After the function has finished, will possibly contain the response to the request.

    """
    response = None
    print ('Trying to login to British Airways using urllib Library (takes about 1 minute for error to occur)')
    # Create request to URL.
    req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.britishairways.com/travel/loginr/public/en_us")

    # Set request headers.
    req.add_header("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.add_header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
    req.add_header("Origin", "https://www.britishairways.com")
    req.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11")
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.add_header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    req.add_header("Referer", "https://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_us")
    req.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
    req.add_header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
    req.add_header("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")
    req.add_header("Cookie", 'BIGipServerba.com-port80=997762723.20480.0000; v1st=EDAB42A278BE913B; BIGipServerba.com-port81=997762723.20736.0000; BA_COUNTRY_CHOICE_COOKIE=us; Allow_BA_Cookies=accepted; BA_COUNTRY_CHOICE_COOKIE=US; BAAUTHKEY=BA4760A2434L; BA_ENROLMENT_APPLICATION_COOKIE=1356219482491AT; BASessionA=wKG4QWGSTggNGnsLTnrgQnMxGMyzvspGLCYpjdSZgv2pSgYN1YRn!-1893405604!clx42al01-wl01.baplc.com!7001!-1!-407095676!clx43al01-wl01.baplc.com!7001!-1; HOME_AD_DISPLAY=1; previousCountryInfo=us; opvsreferrer=functional/home/home_us.jsp; realreferrer=; __utma=28787695.2144676753.1356203603.1356216924.1356219076.6; __utmb=28787695.15.10.1356219076; __utmc=28787695; __utmz=28787695.1356203603.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); fsr.s={"v":-2,"rid":"d464cf7-82608645-1f31-3926-49807","ru":"http://www.britishairways.com/travel/globalgateway.jsp/global/public/en_","r":"www.britishairways.com","st":"","to":5,"c":"https://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_us","pv":31,"lc":{"d0":{"v":31,"s":true}},"cd":0,"f":1356219889982,"sd":0}')

    # Set request body.
    body = b"Directional_Login=&eId=109001&password=p4ssword&membershipNumber=python_noob"

    # Get response to request.


    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, body)
        print ('it worked')
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "An exception of type {0} occured, these were the arguments:\n{1!r}"
        print (msg.format(type(e).__name__, e.args))

    return



def main():
    get_BA_login_using_urllib()
    print()
    get_BA_login_using_requests()
    return


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I'd say you managed to create a malformed or illegal request, and the server (or even proxy) on the other side simply refuses to process it.

1. *Do* use the `requests` library. It's excellent. Urllib is *quite* outdated (and, well, not fun to use at all.)
2. Get rid of nearly all of the custom headers. In particular `Content-Length`, `Keep-Alive`, `Connection` and `Cookie`. The first three you should let the requests library take care of, as they're part of the HTTP 1.1 protocol. With regards to the `Cookie`: that, too, will be handled by the `requests` library, depending on how you use sessions. (You might want to consult the documentation there.) Without having any previous cookies, you'll probably get something like a 401 when you try to access the site, or you'll be (transparently) redirected to a login-page. Doing the login will set the correct cookies, after which you should be able to re-try the original request.
3. If you use a dict for the post-data, you won't need the `Content-Type` header either. You might want to experiment with using unicode-values in said dict. I've found that that sometimes made a difference.

In other words: try to remove as much as you can, and then build it up from there. Doing things like this typically should not cost more than a handful of lines. Now, scraping a web page, that's another matter: try 'beautifulsoup' for that.

P.S.: Don't **ever** post cookie-data on public forums: they might contain personal or otherwise sensitive data that shady characters might be able to abuse.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  I will continue to use the requests library.  The main problem I have here is that when I make the request I just get the 10054 error back after a minute.  I have tried all different combinations of sending the Post data.  No form data, No Header Data, No form & Header data, different header data, etc.  Every combination so far exceptions with a 10054 error.  Again, I just sent same info I saw from fiddler.  Any other suggestions in narrowing down exactly what I should sent.  At least, get something back instead of an exception?

Comment: I did find something here about problems with windows and requests here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167907/https-request-results-in-reset-connection-in-windows-with-python-3.  I will look into it. On a side note. I successfully scaped Amerian and United with Beatifulsoup :)  Thanks for the cookie posting tip!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in the windows versions of Python 3.3 that is the cause of my problem.  I used the answer from here

[HTTPS request results in reset connection in Windows with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167907/https-request-results-in-reset-connection-in-windows-with-python-3)

to make progress with urllib version of my script.  I would like to use Requests so I need to figure out how to do the SSL downgrade work around with that module.  I will make that a separate thread. If anybody has an answer to that you can post here as well. thx.